# Change django-autocomplete-light html property

Tags: django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

**1st How do i change a default html property on django-autocomplete-light?**
**2nd How does django renders the html elements from a form widget?**

Hi there! I'm using django-autocomplete-light v3.

*1st I will show you how to understand my problem*
*2nd I'going to ask you for any help*

**Would you like to try django-autocomplete-light in less than a minute and help me?**

You may follow the steps from here:
https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/install.html

Or just:
`pip install django-autocomplete-light`

*Then, to let Django find the static files we need by adding to INSTALLED_APPS, before 
django.contrib.admin and grappelli if present:*

```
'dal',
'dal_select2',
# 'grappelli',
'django.contrib.admin',
```

*Install the demo project*
*Install the demo project in a temporary virtualenv for testing purpose:*

```
cd /tmp
virtualenv -p python3 dal_env
source dal_env/bin/activate
pip install django
pip install -e git+https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light.git#egg=django-autocomplete-light
cd dal_env/src/django-autocomplete-light/test_project/
pip install -r requirements.txt
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py createsuperuser
./manage.py runserver
# go to http://localhost:8000/admin/ and login
```

**Now you are able to help!!!**

*1.1 Log in to your admin panel*
*1.2 scroll until you see "SELECT2_ONE_TO_ONE" and click*
*1.3 Add a new Tmodel clicking in the 'plus' button from the right*
*1.4 Go to the Inspection mode on you Browser (**ctrl+shift+i**)and click on any select field there*

*i don't have enough reputation to post an image, but you can se it in this link here:*
https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/850#issuecomment-370982681

Now, you can see something alike the one from the image shown.

What i'm trying to do is to change the *style* property of the second  above the input of the select and that is what a want you to help me with.

I want to change the file where that "style='width:434px'" is written to "style='width:100%'" but i can't find it anywhere, because i don't know how does django renders the html elements or from where do they come.

I also have django-autocomplite-light available on a personal project which i didn´t share here to avoid big explanations. :)

**2 I would be very thankful for any help!**

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, i just changed the min-width property of the main class of the element like so:

```
.select2-container {
    min-width: 18.5em !important;
}
```

Not what i was looking for but...